# Grid Children Index

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Hi guys I am creating one Silverlight project in which i am adding control at runtime by using stack panel and grid layout control to format into proper  layout like data forms.

In  one of situation i am adding grid columns at runtime and after some columns like previously it has 3 columns and now i am adding 2 more columns at the 2nd index and also updated the rest index's. up to this all fine. 
but when i am getting children of grid the like for first row. i am getting  1,4,5,2,3 as their children index. 
I want to get them as  1 2 3 4 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `Insert` method instead of modifying the index.  For example:

```
<Grid x:Name="DataGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="LastName" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

then in code:

```
// Insert the first name StackPanel before the existing last name panel
DataGrid.Children.Insert(0, firstNameStackPanel);
```